# How to add react dev tools to chrome when debugging in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

when debugging in vscode in "launch chrome" mode, raises a nice and clean chrome instance, without any extension installed. 
It is good, but in some cases I need react-dev-tools extension and have to run regular chrome to get this done.
Is it any way to have clean debugging chrome, but with dev tools added?

launch configuration is usual:

`{ "type": "chrome",
   "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome:3000",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
  }`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding this line to your launch configuration, launch.json:

```
"runtimeArgs": ["--load-extension=${env:userprofile}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/3.2.3_0"]
```

**Some limitations**

1. Installation points to local folder based on ID of Chrome extension (enable developer mode to see it) - "fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi"
2. Path also points to a specific version (3.2.3_0), which may break on future releases of React dev tools
3. Chrome gives a warning "Disable developer mode extensions" when an extension is loaded locally

Sources

1. [VS Code Variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)
2. [Chrome command line switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: If you need multiple extensions, use comma separator like so: "runtimeArgs": [ "--load-extension=${env:userprofile}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd/2.15.3_0,${env:userprofile}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/3.4.2_0" ]

Comment: This is ok for Windows. On Mac the location of extensions is: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`

Comment: What are the paths for chromium on Linux? or What are these paths represent so I can look for them my self?

Comment: i got a "failed to load extension: .Manifest file is missing or unreadable" when tryng this with version 4.24.3_0 of redux dev tools.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get the react-devtools tab with following steps.

1. Install the react-devtools extension in the window opened by VScode (Again)
2. Reopen devtools (CMD-ALT-i)
3. Refresh the page.

I know there could be a better way. I think the chrome window opened by VScode must be protected from loading Extensions like in private mode. Answers welcome.

Comment: I used this approach on my MacBook. It worked well for me.

Comment: This approach was the only thing that worked for me; on a PC with Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

We are going to run Chrome with a **debug flag** and then **attach** VScode debugger into it.

### Steps

1. Add the following to the `package.json` `start` **script**:

```
    "start": "'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' --remote-debugging-port=9222 & react-scripts start",
```

Basically what it does it runs the Chrome executable with the `--remote-debugging-port=9222` flag. (Note that the `&` operator launches a background process so the script can proceed to the next command)

2. Add a **launch configuration** to the `launch.json` file:

```
{
   "type": "chrome",
   "request": "attach",
   "name": "Attach",
   "port": 9222
}
```

3. **Run** the development server by running `npm start` in the terminal.

### Caveats

Note that this solution points to a Chrome installation on a **MacOS**. For other OS modify the location of chrome in step 1.